# Add caption on top of two table in standalone

Tags: tables, captions, standalone

How can I add a caption on top of two table in standalone document? e.g.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,convert={outfile=\jobname.jpg}]{standalone}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Kaiti TC}
\usepackage{ifthen}
%
\usepackage{caption}
\def\tand{&}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
%
\begin{document}
\newcounter{zh}
\newcounter{us}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
%
\begin{tabular}{|c|g|}
\hline
  \setcounter{zh}{0}%
  \setcounter{us}{10}%
   China \tand US \\ \hline%
  \whiledo{\thezh<12}{%
      \thezh \tand \theus \\ \hline%
       \ifnum\value{zh}=11\hline\end{tabular}\fi
       \stepcounter{zh}%
        \stepcounter{us}%
       \ifnum\value{us}>23 \setcounter{us}{0}\fi
  }%
   \begin{tabular}{|c|g|}
\hline
  \setcounter{zh}{12}%
  \setcounter{us}{22}%
   China \tand US \\ \hline%
  \whiledo{\thezh<24}{%
      \thezh \tand \theus \\ \hline%
       \ifnum\value{zh}=23\hline\end{tabular}\fi
       \stepcounter{zh}%
        \stepcounter{us}%
       \ifnum\value{us}>23 \setcounter{us}{0}\fi
  }%
\end{document}
```

Current output is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to put your tabulars in a unique tabular, and the latter in `threeparttable`, which has the advantage to measure the tabular width. Then use a normal `caption`. I take the opportunity to point that you don't have to load `color` since you load `xcolor`, nor `colortbl` since you load it (xcolor) with option `[table]`:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,convert={outfile=\jobname.jpg}]{standalone}%
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Kaiti TC}
\usepackage{ifthen}
%
\usepackage{caption, float, threeparttable}
\def\tand{&}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
%
\begin{document}
\newcounter{zh}
\newcounter{us}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
%b

\begin{threeparttable}%
\captionsetup{skip=4pt}%
\caption{Some caption}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|g|}
\hline
  \setcounter{zh}{0}%
  \setcounter{us}{10}%
   China \tand US \\ \hline%
  \whiledo{\thezh<12}{%
      \thezh \tand \theus \\ \hline%
       \ifnum\value{zh}=11\hline%
       \end{tabular}\fi
\stepcounter{zh}%
\stepcounter{us}%
\ifnum\value{us}>23 \setcounter{us}{0}\fi%
  }%
   \begin{tabular}{|c|g|}
\hline
  \setcounter{zh}{12}%
  \setcounter{us}{22}%
   China \tand US \\ \hline%
  \whiledo{\thezh<24}{%
      \thezh \tand \theus \\ \hline%
       \ifnum\value{zh}=23\hline%
       \end{tabular}\fi
       \stepcounter{zh}%
        \stepcounter{us}%
       \ifnum\value{us}>23 \setcounter{us}{0}\fi
  }%
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you are using the `caption` package, you can use `\captionof{table}{<text>}` without a float. To place it on top of the two tables, you can use a `minipage`, that is:

```
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\captionof{table}{The caption}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{...}... \end{tabular}% \hfill or \quad here?
\begin{tabular}{...}... \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

But being a `standalone` class, why the hell you need the `caption` package and a `\captionof` command?

```
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\centering
Table 1. The caption
\begin{tabular}{...}... \end{tabular}% 
\begin{tabular}{...}... \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```